# Do magical words differ between languages in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

As we know Hogwarts and its surrounding environment are located in Great Britain and so wizards and witches speak British English. But we see students from various ethnicities at Hogwarts, which means wizarding is present all over world.

Now in the real world there are different words for same object depending upon British English and American English like football/soccer, cab/taxi and many more...

Does this affect the wizarding world, especially spells?

For example, does “Avada Kedavara” change in America?

Comment: It just so happens the spell you chose is a rendition of the old aramaic spell Abracadabra. With cadabra wittily changed to cadaver (latin for corpse). As with most spells, they are not english in origin, but Latin.

Comment: “we see students from various ethnicity at Hogwarts which means wizarding world is present all over world” — we do have different ethnicities here in Britain, so wizarding could be purely British — xenophobic but not racist.

Comment: well we know that wizards from egypt were doing magic in another language, and egyptian wizards would not be using latin spells anyway.but their spells could have been incorporated into the newer spell books anyway, it apears wizards knowledge follows typical European knowledge routes, egypt/middle east, into rome, into the rest of Europe, though they wouldn't have had quite a barrier from seeing wizards in asia so they probably had better cross pollination of ideas.

Comment: Russian is not a Latin based language and niether is Japanese. Did the student from Koldovstoretz use different spells? Or the Japanese student from Mahoutokoro?

Comment: I was on-the-fence about closing this as a dupe; if you think they're different, edit to clarify and ping me to reopen.