# Language of the Magic?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Hogwarts is in Britain, and all students speak English. Thus all the spell we have seen have English dialect. But what about the wizards of countries outside Britain?

Like when Hermione went to France and Ron went to Egypt. I am sure none of those wizards cast their spells in English... but somehow this thing was never discussed or mentioned?

Does this mean that every spell one cast in English has its counter spell in other languages? Each one of the spells in each one of the languages? Then what about the spells that one wizard invents himself and never discloses in  public, like Sectumsempra (Invented by Snape and there could be tons of others from other wizards)?

Does this also mean that other wizards of other countries may have invented spells of their own, in their own language which somehow they have kept secret? There should be a check on things like this. Does the ministry keep track of such spells? If yes then how?

Comment: Does *Avada Kedavra* look English to you?

Comment: Lumos, Crucio, Expelliarmus and many other spells seem of English dialect.

Comment: All of the spell names you just mentioned are latin or latin based

Comment: see also: [Do magical words differ between languages in Harry Potter?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79894/5184)

Answer (score 0):

#### The spells are primarily in Latin, or at least derived from something very similar.

Most, if not all, European languages are derived from Latin. And probably many more besides.

[Spells with Incantations of Latin Origin](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Spells_with_Incantations_of_Latin_Origin)

Comment: So does this mean every wizard around the world cast the same spell in the same Latin language?

Comment: @Harsimrat this [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15238/20393) has everything you need.

Comment: Romance languages are descended from Latin. Teutonic and Slavic languages, not so much. And let's not even get into Hungarian or Finish...